# jqModal not working

Tags: javascript, html, jqmodal

I was trying to test out some working code from http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/   to get an idea of how this works, but I am unable to get the code to work. I'm trying to use the pop up dialog box part, and I am testing the code from the defaults, which is the first example, in the examples section. here is what I had copied and tried testing out. the part that is not working is the dialog box popping up. i receive an error say....  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
<html>

<head>
<title> test </title>

<style type = "text/css">


.jqmWindow {
display:none;

position: fixed;
top: 17%;
left: 50%;

margin-left: -300px;
width: 600px;

background-color: #EEE;
color: #333;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 12px;
}

.jqmOverlay { background-color: #000; }


# html .jqmWindow {
 position: absolute;
 top: expression((document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) +     Math.round(17 * (document.documentElement.offsetHeight || document.body.clientHeight) / 100) + 'px');
}

</style>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$('#dialog').jqm();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" class="jqModal">view</a>
...
<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog">

<a href="#" class="jqmClose">Close</a>
<hr>
<em>READ ME</em> -->
This is a "vanilla plain" jqModal window. Behavior and appeareance extend far beyond   this.
The demonstrations on this page will show off a few possibilites. I recommend walking
through each one to get an understanding of jqModal <em>before</em> using it.

<br /><br />
You can view the sourcecode of examples by clicking the Javascript, CSS, and HTML tabs.
Be sure to checkout the <a href="README">documentation</a> too!

<br /><br />
<em>NOTE</em>; You can close windows by clicking the tinted background known as the  "overlay".
Clicking the overlay will have no effect if the "modal" parameter is passed, or if the
overlay is disabled.
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is indeed your entire HTML, then the reason $ is not defined is that you have not included jQuery (which defines $ and uses it a lot as shorthand). Your code includes neither the jQuery library nor the jqModal script. (Admittedly all of the examples on the jqModal site are extracts rather than full code so they take this step for granted.)

Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jqModal.js"></script>
```

in your `<head>`, adjusting the path for jQModal.js as appropriate.